# Unable to change Hugepagesize value in Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ram

I'm trying to modify the Hugepagesize value in Ubuntu 16.04.3 from the default value of 1024 kB to 2G, but it always stays at the default value even after I apply the change and reboot.  It picks up changes I make to the number of hugepages parameter, but not the size of the hugepages.  I have plenty of memory on this system to accommodate the number of pages I'm configuring.

Relevant output:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
default_hugepagesz=2G hugepagesz=2G hugepages=4

HugePages_Total:       4
HugePages_Free:        4
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       1024 kB
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure is the "2G" huge page supported by your system.

The supported huge page size determined by hardware & OS. Most of modern Intel platform support up to 1G huge page.

https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages

https://lwn.net/Articles/448571/

Answer (score -1):

Answer is simple:
execute as root

```
sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=256
```

`nr_hugepages` number is in MB.

Comment: I have root access. vm.nr_hugepages only changes the number of huge pages.  I need to change the size of each individual page (Hugepagesize value in my original post).  I'm not having any issues changing the number of huge pages.